How to pass a message from cirrus.js to the streamer equivalent to the frontend stream.emitUIInteraction
I am using the Unreal Engine 5 Pixel Streaming Github:
https://github.com/EpicGamesExt/PixelStreamingInfrastructure/tree/UE5.3
I have been sending stream.emitUIInteraction("Reset") from my frontend without problem. However, my application needs to start sending this on a player disconnect from the cirrus.js in the signalling server itself.
How would I construct equivalent functionality here from the signalling server? As I look through the code it seems like I'd need to set up a data channel which could be a lot of work. Is there a simpler solution I'm missing?
